# Not able to pass string from php to javascript when onclick on div and not able to give the parameterized link as innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to load a file when on click on the different text in another div. I have 5 div. And also I need to fix some default content in all the div. div should override and call the file when clicking on the text which is in another div. I am able to call two files in two different files when I click on the text in the left div. But when I try to pass a string from PHP to javascript I am not able to do that. I want to parameterize the link to the different text. How can I achieve this? If I try to assign a PHP variable to it is giving nothing in output. Thanks in advance.

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>A div layout</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script>
            function load_home(link){

                document.write(link);

                var project="<?php echo $name; ?>";

                var table_link='table_'+link+'.php';

                var graph_link='graph_'+link+'.php';


                document.getElementById("tables").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="table_link" height=100% width=100%></object>';
                document.getElementById("graph").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="graph_link" height=100% width=100%></object>';

            }
    </script>

    <div id="header" style="width: 100%; height:7%; background-color: green; color: white;">Merahkee Tech Solutions
    </div>

    <div id="tree" style="width: 20%; height:88%; background-color: pink; color: white; float:left">
    <?php
    $name="customer";
        echo '<nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href ="#" onclick="load_home('.$name.')">Pebble</a></li>
            <li><a href ="#" onclick="load_home()">Jenkins</a></li>
            <li><a href ="#" onclick="load_home()">Tomcat</a></li>
            <li><a href ="#" onclick="load_home()">Jira</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>'
    ?>
    </div>

    <div id="tables" style="width: 80%; height:35%; background-color: skyblue; color: white; float:left">This is default content

    </div>

    <div id="graph" style="width: 70%; height:53%; background-color: lightblue; color: white; float:left">This is trial graph div
    </div>

    <div id="dropdown" style="width: 10%; height:53%; background-color: pink; color: white; float:left">This is trial dropdown div
    </div>

    <div id="footer" style="width: 100%; height:5%; background-color: green; color: white; float:left">This is a footer div
    </div>


</body>
```

Now I am not getting anything once I click on text in the first div.

Comment: `<script></script>` should be at the end of `<body>`.

Comment: `var project="<?php echo $name; ?>";` This will not work? `<?php echo 'var project = '.$name.'; ?>` will work, but the var does not get used in js?

Comment: Tried it. Still the same output I am getting.

Comment: Hello Brainfeeder, it is not working for me..:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your string in ' or " when you pass it to the javascript function so the function know that you are sending string 
so you instead of :

```
echo '<nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href ="#" onclick="load_home('.$name.')">Pebble</a></li>
            <li><a href ="#" onclick="load_home()">Jenkins</a></li>
            <li><a href ="#" onclick="load_home()">Tomcat</a></li>
            <li><a href ="#" onclick="load_home()">Jira</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>';
```

you Do:

```
echo "<nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href =\"#\" onclick=\"load_home('{$name}')\">Pebble</a></li>
            <li><a href =\"#\" onclick=\"load_home()\">Jenkins</a></li>
            <li><a href =\"#\" onclick=\"load_home()\">Tomcat</a></li>
            <li><a href =\"#\" onclick=\"load_home()\">Jira</a> </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>";
```

And put your script in the end of your body

Comment: Great, it is working...:). How can I parameterize that?

Comment: How can I pass more than one parameter? and How to parameterize the link and give as data in innerHTML?

Comment: if your function accept more than one parameter Like  `function load_home(par1,par2,par3)` then you send it in php like this `onclick=\"load_home('{$name}','{$other_par1}','{$other_par2}')\"`

Comment: Working fine...:)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: there is a right sign (✓) beside the start of the answer click on it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>A div layout</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function load_home(link) {

            document.write(link);

            var project=link;

            var table_link='table_'+link+'.php';
            var graph_link='graph_'+link+'.php';


            document.getElementById("tables").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="table_link" height=100% width=100%></object>';
            document.getElementById("graph").innerHTML='<object type="type/html" data="graph_link" height=100% width=100%></object>';

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="header" style="width: 100%; height:7%; background-color: green; color: white;">
        Merahkee Tech Solutions
    </div>

    <div id="tree" style="width: 20%; height:88%; background-color: pink; color: white; float:left">

        <?php $name = "customer"; ?>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href ="#" onclick="load_home('<?php echo $name ?>');">Pebble</a></li>
                <li><a href ="#" onclick="load_home('<?php echo $name ?>');">Jenkins</a></li>
                <li><a href ="#" onclick="load_home('<?php echo $name ?>');">Tomcat</a></li>
                <li><a href ="#" onclick="load_home('<?php echo $name ?>');">Jira</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div id="tables" style="width: 80%; height:35%; background-color: skyblue; color: white; float:left">
        This is default content
    </div>

    <div id="graph" style="width: 70%; height:53%; background-color: lightblue; color: white; float:left">
        This is trial graph div
    </div>

    <div id="dropdown" style="width: 10%; height:53%; background-color: pink; color: white; float:left">
        This is trial dropdown div
    </div>

    <div id="footer" style="width: 100%; height:5%; background-color: green; color: white; float:left">
        This is a footer div
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In your Snippet, I see single/double quote issue, try pasting my whole snippet.

```
<li><a href ="#" onclick="load_home('<?php echo $name ?>');">Pebble</a></li>
```

See **'**`<?php echo $name; ?>`**'** the single quotes around PHP variable being echoed.

Comment: it is working, but I want it to be inside php. Is it possible?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Prajna, In your $name variable you can set your php value.
Or am I not getting to the point, explain how you want or explain further.

Comment: I got the answer for that..:)

Comment: Ok than if my answer is helpful please up-vote it. Thank you.